# How can I view a history of posts to my Facebook wall?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to view a listing of old posts to my Facebook wall? I've been using Facebook for a number of years, and I have accumulated hundreds of postings on my wall. How long are those posts stored on Facebook's servers, and how can I look at the old ones?

I know you can click the link "view older posts", but that only takes you back one page a time, and to get to the really old posts would take hours that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [ArchivedBook](http://archivedbook.nckh.jp/)

> Archivedbook is a great way to review your Facebook profile's history!
>
> - View all the old wall messages from your Facebook friends.
> - View all your old status updates.
> - Check how many likes and comments got posted on your profile since the last 30 days.
> - ...and you can also view the same data about your friends!

Comment: Awesome! Excellent answer...

Comment: Looks like it no longer works.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it doesn't allow searching

Answer (score 3):

With the new [Facebook Timeline](https://www.facebook.com/about/timeline), this has become easier to do allowing one to browse posts by year and month.

[image: Facebook Timeline]

Comment: I'm sorry but this isn't helpful since the Timeline feature is not live yet.

Comment: @TonyR Timeline is available in New Zealand and to Facebook Developers and to 1M or so users who signed up as developers as early access.

Comment: A-ha that explains it. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

You should also check out http://www.StatusHistory.com  It allows you to search/filter/sort your Facebook statuses plus get a cool stats page

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to leave Facebook, here's the Facebook App I made a while ago: https://apps.facebook.com/searchmyposts/

> Facebook Search My Posts allows you to search through everything you ever posted on your Facebook wall.